# Socket timeout using signalR when using Azure Emulator, it works fine if i run the mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I have a MVC 4 Project using signalR. I start a thread that send a msg every 5 sec to all clients. This runs fine. I can see the msgs on the clients. When i run the Azure Project with the MVC project as a role. Clients receive the first 2 or 3 msgs and then it times out and start behaving odd.

What differences are there when running a azure project and a mvc project, the emulator starts iss express also so i cant see what the issues might be.

Anyone have some suggestions for where to go next.

Comment: Are running more than on instance?

Comment: When deployed to Azure there are no issues, so it is a local issue.